# Rational Zero Theorem in C++

Tags: c++, math

So I've been trying to make a program which asks for the coefficients of a grade 3 polynomial function, returns the factors of the first and last coefficient, and then applies the theorem to list the possible cero rationals of the function

I have managed to ask for the coefficients, and list the factors, but I'm having problems to find all the possible combination of ceros

Basically, I get a list of numbers assigned to p, and another list of numbers assigned to q, all integers, then I gotta list all the possible combinations of p/q, copy of my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a,b,c,d,x;
float p,q,h;
int main ()
{
    cout<<"Ingrese los coeficientes (numeros enteros) del polinomio de grado 3 segun el orden de ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese a:";
    cin>>a;
    while (a==0)
    {
        cout<<"Asegurese el valor de a sea distinto de cero"<<endl<<"Ingrese a:";
        cin>>a;
    }
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese b:";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese c:";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese d:";
    cin>>d;
    while (d==0)
    {
        cout<<"Asegurese el valor de d sea distinto de cero"<<endl<<"Ingrese d:";
        cin>>d;
    }
    cout<<d<<endl;
    cout<<"Su polinomio de tercer grado es: "<<a<<"x^3 + "<<b<<"x^2 + "<<c<<"x + "<<d<<endl;
    if(a>d)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
        {   
            if (a%i==0)
            {
                q=a/i;
                cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<a<<" es:"<<endl;
                cout<<"+-";
                cout<<q<<","<<endl;
            }       
            if (d%i==0)
            {
                p=d/i;
                cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<d<<" es:"<<endl;
                cout<<"+-";
                cout<<p<<","<<endl;
            }   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=d;i++)
        {   
            if (a%i==0)
            {
                q=a/i;
                cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<a<<" es:"<<endl;
                cout<<"+-";
                cout<<q<<","<<endl;
            }
            if (d%i==0)
            {
                p=d/i;
                cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<d<<" es:"<<endl;
                cout<<"+-";
                cout<<p<<","<<endl;
            }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm only permitted to use if, while, do while

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays?  If so, store the p values in 1 array and q values in another, then you can loop through all the array entries checking each fraction to see if it is a zero of the equation.

Comment: Also, you say you are only allowed to use `if, while, do` but then you are using `for` in your code.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yeah forgot to include that command, also i'm not allowed to use arrays, what I have in mind is, find the first value of p, and then find all the values of q, so i can find the first possible combinations, then I would find the second value of p, and then again divide by all the values of q

Comment: @MichaelDorgan but I have problem putting that in code, I managed to print it like that with this, problem is, it keeps printing the values of p after finding all the values

for (int i=1;i<=a;i++)
 { 
   if (a%i==0)
   {
    q=a/i;
    cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<a<<" es:"<<endl;
    cout<<"+-";
    cout<<q<<","<<endl;
   }
   for (int k=1;k<=a;k++)
   {
    if (d%k==0)
    {
     p=d/k;
     cout<<"Un factor del numero "<<d<<" es:"<<endl;
     cout<<"+-";
     cout<<p<<","<<endl;
    }

Comment: Without arrays, you should create a function to evaluate the zeros - it accepts all the coefficients and the p and q values and have it return a boolean.  It does the math on the given values to determine if it is a zero.  Once that is written, you will need to write a "nested loop" with all possible p and q values and feed that into your zero checker function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full solution, but should give you an idea of how to start:

```
// Notice I am passing the integer values of p and q in here.  
// We could just pass the decimal fraction instead.
bool ZeroCheckFunction(int a, int b, int c, int p, int q);

...
if(a>d)
{
  for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
  {   
    if (a%i==0)
    {
      q=a/i;

      for(int j=1;j<=a;j++)
      {   
        if (d%j==0)
        {
          p=d/j;
          if(ZeroCheckFunction(a,b,c,p,q))
          {
            //This is a zero of the function - do what is needed.
          }
        }
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

This nested form will check all `p` values against the known `q` and should help you move your assignment further along.